# Bash - Scroll through a string aesthetically

Tags: bash, shell-script, scrolling

So, I was trying to create an aesthetic horizontally scrolling text in the console using bash. I wasn't sure how to go about this. here's an example:

```
Original string: Hi! How are you doing on this fine evening?

1st loop:
Hi! H
2nd:
i! Ho
3rd:
! How
4th:
 How
```

and so on. How would I go about this? I would preferably have it delete the last printed loop so it is a smooth scrolling string.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!
(Also feel free to ask questions, this description was kinda bad :P)

Comment: Printing a raw `\r` is probably your friend here. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

As the other said you should use `echo` or `printf` with carriage return `\r`.

So what you want is to print only 5 chars per loop you could use the script below for that behavior:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

null=$'\0'
text="Hi! How are you doing on this fine evening? ${null}"

#while :; do
count=0
for (( i = 0; i < "${#text}"; i++ )); do
   printf "\r%s" "${text:$i:5}"
   sleep 0.3
done
#done
echo
```

With this line `printf "\r%s" "${text:$i:5}"` I'm printing 5 characters per loop, where the `$i` is the current index and the `5` is the length of the string to print. 
For example, if you print the `text` variable as follows:

```
printf "%s" "${text:0:5}"
#Output
Hi! H
printf "%s" "${text:1:5}"
#Output
i! Ho
#and so on
```

If you wish to print all the string and remove each character from left per loop you can use this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

null=$'\0'
text="Hi! How are you doing on this fine evening? ${null}"

#while :; do
count=0
for (( i = 0; i < "${#text}"; i++ )); do
   printf "\r%s" "${text:$i}"
   sleep 0.3
done
#done
echo
```

The code above will print:

**In first loop:**

```
Hi! How are you doing on this fine evening?
```

**In second loop:**

```
i! How are you doing on this fine evening?
```

**In third loop:**

```
! How are you doing on this fine evening?
```

and so on.

**Note:** The variable `$null` should be used to avoid printing at the end of the string its last character, in this case `?`. And if you want a infinite loop your should uncomment  the lines `#while :; do` and `#done`.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit hacky, but I believe it's the effect you are describing. In the output each of these lines will overwrite the previous entry so that it produces something like the old `<marquee>`
tags, but in the terminal.

```
Hello There!
ello There! He
o There! Hello
There! Hello
ere! Hello The
e! Hello There
Hello There!
ello There! He
lo There! Hell
There! Hello
here! Hello Th
re! Hello Ther
! Hello There!
Hello There! H
llo There! Hel
o There! Hello
There! Hello T
here! Hello Th
e! Hello There
Hello There!
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function slice_loop () { ## grab a slice of a string, and if you go past the end loop back around
    local str="$1"
    local start=$2
    local how_many=$3
    local len=${#str};

    local result="";

    for ((i=0; i < how_many; i++))
    do
        local index=$(((start+i) % len)) ## Grab the index of the needed char (wrapping around if need be)
        local char="${str:index:1}" ## Select the character at that index
        local result="$result$char" ## Append to result
    done

    echo -n $result
}

msg="Hello There! ";
begin=0

while :
do
    slice=$(slice_loop "$msg" $begin 14);
    echo -ne "\r";
    echo -n $slice;
    echo -ne "              \r";
    sleep 0.08;
    ((begin=begin+1));
done
```

Save that in a file and run it and you should see the string `"Hello There!"` scroll past. It's a bit jittery but you can tweak that to make it a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

`echo -e "\r"` is your friend: \r is the carriage return symbol (imagine you're sitting in front of a typewriter!) which puts your cursor back at the beginning of the current line.

So,

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "foobar"
#     ^---------- don't print a newline at the end of the line!
sleep 1
echo -e -n "\rbaz"
#        ^------- don't print a newline at the end of the line!
#     ^---------- evaluate escape sequences like \r
echo -e -n "\rB"
```

will print `foobar`, wait a second, then overwrite `foo` with `baz` and then directly overwrite the small with a capital `B`, yielding `Bazbar`.

That should be all you need for a scroller!

If you really want to do animations, this will end up being too complicated. You'd want to write a program that uses a library that can actually modify arbitrary positions on your terminal. (n)curses is such a library – even Python has a module for it! I'd recommend checking it out. [Here's an example](https://github.com/marcusmueller/curses_animation).